# Laravel's Model Factory throwing syntax error

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have tried using factory to create number of Users through the use of the stock migration/model/factory definition and the following command ran within php artisan tinker: `$user = factory(App\User::class)->make();`

I have made no changes to the function as you can see below;

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
        'password' => bcrypt(str_random(10)),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

Yet I get the following error: `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting']'`

***UPDATE***

I must have deleted something somewhere along the line that caused this error, I have no idea what it was but I started a fresh project and I no longer have the error. Thankyou for trying to help!

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error. I have the files under source control so verified that no lines were deleted...Again no idea what the cause is, but would prefer to avoid restarting with a brand new project... any suggestions?

Comment: This question spent over 2yrs but no answer is right

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you wrap the factory call in parentheses, with the object operator immediately after? Though, expecting a closing `]` makes me think you have forgotten one, much further up not where you're looking.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the class in quotes:

```
$user = factory("App\User")->make();
```

Comment: Actually according to the documentation both are fine, this is just easier for use in PHPStorm because it means I can click on the class and it will open it for me.

Answer (score 0):

When I did my project and debug some error like that and solution as bellow:

1. Let check list of files which bug show for you.
2. Let check the line's the first file of above list.
3. if got error like this: "unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)", it maybe redundant '->' at the line above.